# Livewire how to $emit event on select change (wire:model)

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

Livewire how to $emit event on `<select>` change (wire:model)

I need to fire event (fetch some data from DB in another component) on simple `<select>` change.

```
<select id="hall" wire:model="hall_id">...</select>
```

How to watch changes for this model? On VueJS we just set $watch or $computed properties, I believe in livewire should be something similar. It's strange why there is no `wire:change` directive.

This is how I'm trying to emit event now:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Event;
use App\Models\Hall;
use Livewire\Component;

class ShowReservationForm extends Component
{
    public $hall_id = '';

    protected $queryString = [
        'hall_id' => ['except' => ''],
    ];

    public function mounted()
    {
        //
    }

    public function updatedHallId($name, $value)
    {
        $this->emit('hallChanged', $value);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-reservation-form', [
            'halls' => Hall::all(),
        ]);
    }

    public function getHallEventsProperty()
    {
        return Event::where('hall_id', $this->hall_id)->get();
    }
}
```

and catch it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class ShowReservations extends Component
{
    protected $listeners = ['hallChanged'];

    public $showTable = false;

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-reservations');
    }

    public function hallChanged()
    {
        $this->showTable = true;
    }
}
```

Must be missing something obvious.

Comment: Doesn't work at all, trying put `$this->emit('hallChanged')` everywhere ;D

Comment: Do you enter the `updatedHallId()` method when the field is changed? Add a `dd('Test');` or similar in that method.

Comment: There's not really a need for `wire:change`, because you just listen for the updated event for that property from the component.

Comment: dd() in updatedHallId indeed working but this part seams not: $this->emit('hallChanged', $value); Or maybe something wrong with $listeners

Comment: And both components are on the same page? They cannot emit events to other users or other pages. You need broadcasting for that.

Comment: Yes, they are on dashboard.blade.php @livewire('show-reservation-form') and @livewire('show-reservations')

Comment: And have you verified that you enter the `hallChanged` method in your `ShowReservations` component?

Comment: @RomkaLTU please check my answer i tested in my side it is working

Comment: Yes, protected $listeners = ['hallChanged']; Because method are same name, also tried protected $listeners = ['hallChanged' => 'hallChanged']; no dice. @KamleshPaul I don't have problem with change event, only with emitter.

Comment: I ran into a similar problem maybe my question & answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379725/how-can-i-create-dynamic-public-properties-and-data-via-a-parent-component-to-a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's turns out that when receiving event, property value must not be bool?

This will not work:

```
public $showTable = false;
...
public function hallChanged()
    {
        $this->showTable = true;
    }
```

This will work

```
public $showTable = 0;
...
public function hallChanged()
    {
        $this->showTable = 1;
    }
```

Answer (score 19):

use `wire:change`

```php
<select id="hall" wire:model="hall_id" wire:change="change">...</select>
```

then in component

**In ShowReservationForm.php**

```php
public function change()
{
     $this->emit('hallChanged'); 
}
```

then you can listen it on `ShowReservations` component  ref link https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/events

**in ShowReservations.php**

```php
 protected $listeners = ['hallChanged' => 'change'];

public function change()
{
   $this->showTable = true;
}
```

Comment: I actualy don’t want to use JS, It would be very awkward. And I use version 2 of livewire.

Comment: by the way what you are doing with `showTable` ?  you can directly do `@if(!empty($hall_id))   table @endif`

Comment: That table is in another component ant initial state is false and yes I'm doing simple @if statement. So what I'm trying to do is to change that $showTable property to true.

Answer (score 1):

If the code not works, take a look about any [for example jQuery] handle for your select, maybe it handled by [select2](https://select2.org/) script or so, **if so - LiveWire will not work** from scratch. The rigth minimal code is:

**/resources/views/livewire/your-livewire-component.blade.php**

```
<select wire:model="country">
    @foreach($items as $code => $country)
        <option value="{{ $code }}">{{ $country }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

**/app/Http/Livewire/YourLivewireComponent.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Livewire;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Livewire\Component;
class YourLivewireComponent extends Component
{
    public $items;
    public $country; //necessary!
    public function mount($items)
    {
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.your-livewire-component', [
            'items' => ['ES' => 'Spain', 'FI' => 'Finland']
        ]);
    }

    public function updatedCountry($value)
    {
        Log::info('value='.print_r($value, 1));
    }
}
```

**/resources/views/somelaraveltemplate.blade.php**

```
<p>some HTML code</p>
@livewire('your-liveweire-component')
```