# Nesting form selects in Laravel Livewire

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I am converting a bare PHP app into a Laravel app using Livewire. In the app there is a view that has a form select dropdown. Depending on which thing in that dropdown is selected it then shows another form select dropdown, this continues 3 or 4 times.

So it's like..

select a room
then it loads the list of racks in the room selected in the dropdown
select a rack
then it loads the list of shelves on the rack selected in the dropdown
select a shelf
then it loads the list of bins on the shelf selected in the dropdown
select a bin

I can do this fairly easily with JS/AJAX but I am trying to determine if there is a way to do this type of thing only using livewire.

Does anyone have any ideas? I have really been hunting around on Google and github looking for examples of this and haven't found anything.

Comment: Nesting form elements is not valid html if that gives you your answer? You can expose a second select element once you chose the first etc

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203446/livewire-how-to-emit-event-on-select-change-wiremodel seems to show how to emit an event when a select changes. You can probably use that to load additional options and show another select

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `wire:model` attribute to each of your select fields.
Then in component you need to add functions "updated" :

```
// SelectField1 is the name of variable where first select field value is stored. 
// wire:model="selectField1" in view 

public string $selectField1 = '';
public bool $isSelect2Active = false;
public string $selectField2 = '';


public function updatedSelectField1($value){
    if($value == 'correct value'){
        $this->isSelect2Active = true;
    }
}
```

Then in your view you have something like :

```
<select wire:model="selectField1">
    //options
</select>
@if($isSelect2Active)
    <select wire:model="selectField2">
        //options
    </select>
@endif
```

Also you can simply skip function updated and add condition on `$selectField1 == 'value'` directly inside view instead of having specific variable `$isSelect2Active` for it :

```
<select wire:model="selectField1">
    //options
</select>
@if($selectField1 == 'correct value')
    <select wire:model="selectField2">
        //options
    </select>
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks that will help. I just need to load the data from the model depending on which thing is selected in the previous select but thaf should be realllll easy :)